# How to remove a single quote when splitting characters in a string which is represented as a tuple in python

Tags: python

The string is represented as given below:

```
str = '1,1'
```

which is changed to tuple like given below:

```
p = ('1,1',)
```

I need something like the representation that is given below:

```
(1,1)
```

Comment: I'm confused by the title - how does this correspond to "removing a single quote"?

Comment: @mutzmatron -- I'm honestly a little confused about that too -- which is why I took the shotgun approach in my answer (answer 3 questions and hope one of them is the right one).

Comment: @mgilson: hahaha - nice one! Also I agree, I don't like the `eval` approach either - `eval` should be avoided whenever possible!

Comment: One other comment -- If you use `str` as a variable name in your code, you should change it to something else to avoid "shadowing" the (very useful) builtin `str` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
s = '1,1'
p = tuple( int(x) for x in s.split(',') )
```

This causes the tuple elements to be integers which is what it seems like you want.

If you want the tuple elements to be strings, something like this should work:

```
p = tuple( s.split(',') )
```

If your string actually contains quote characters in it, you can remove them `s=s.replace("'")` ...

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this:

```
import ast
s = '1,1'
p = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

edit: made safe per mgilson's insight.

Comment: `eval` will evaluate any expression (e.g. `s = "__import__('os').system('rm -rf ~')"`) which could lead to a very bad day if some joker somehow makes `s` into a malicious string.  `ast.literal_eval` will only evaluate literals and expressions involving literals.  (e.g. strings, lists, tuples, integers, floats, dicts ...)

Answer (score 0):

We could use regex:

```
import re
s = '1,1'
int_tuple = tuple(int(s) for s in re.findall('\\d+', s))
Output: (1, 1)
```